# Why is this query not returning anything in android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT_total_time 
WHERE USER_ID = 2 
    AND LEVEL_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 1 
    AND DATETIME( TIMESTAMP ) BETWEEN DATETIME('now','-7 days') AND DATETIME('now') 
ORDER BY datetime( TIMESTAMP ) ASC
```

and the DB has

```
PRINTING TABLE EVENT_total_time
0 {
    _id=56
    USER_ID=2
    TIMESTAMP=2016-02-15 21:29:29
    EPOCH_TIME=1455571769621
    NEW_VALUE=3.034
    LEVEL_ID=7
    LEVEL_SEQUENCE_NUMBER=1
    EXTRAS={"old_value":0}
  }
1 {
    _id=57
    USER_ID=2
    TIMESTAMP=2016-02-15 21:29:29
    EPOCH_TIME=1455571769822
    NEW_VALUE=3.219
    LEVEL_ID=7
    LEVEL_SEQUENCE_NUMBER=1
    EXTRAS={"old_value":3.034}
  }
```

this query was ran 30sec ago so ... datetime('now') should be 15.02.2016 21:32:00 ....

I ran this query and it produced an empty result. Can someone spot why?

Comment: But your query does not output `datetime('now')`. It returns the **contents of the records** with a timestamp of less than 1 week old. So what is the problem?

Comment: Yes you are using a between datetime. If you want to output only this datetime you have to set the datetime('now') only

Comment: Define "not working". If the query you wrote is providing the results shown, then it seems to be working correctly. If now is `2016-02-15 21:32:00`, then 7 days ago is `2016-02-08 21:32:00`. The records you received both have a date of `2016-02-15 21:29:29`, so that seems correct.

Comment: I will edit the questions

Comment: in this `DATETIME('now','-7 days')` `now` is passed as a string, right? i think it should be `DATETIME(now(),'-7 days')` ?

Comment: It crashed. Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such function: now (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM  EVENT_total_time WHERE USER_ID = 2 AND LEVEL_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = 1 AND DATETIME( TIMESTAMP ) BETWEEN DATETIME(now(),'-7 days') AND DATETIME('now') ORDER BY datetime( TIMESTAMP ) ASC

Comment: sorry just checked `DATETIME('now')` for sqlite is correct